# Renaming iCloud mail address

Tags: icloud, mail.app, apple-id

Guys I'm kind of hopeless after weeks of searching. My problem is the following:

When I created my Apple ID years ago I was young and didn't really understand the way Apple ID worked. I used shared it with my brother and it was perfectly fine except that he managed to mess up my iCloud mail to look like "mybrothersname@icloud.com" instead of "myname@icloud.com". Years passed and now I would really like to use the email service offered by iCloud, but seems like there is no way to change the mail address' name.

Before telling me, I know I could use an alias, but it just annoys me. I would like to have my own name on the @icloud.com mail address generated with my ID. I would simply make a fresh Apple ID, but I just managed to buy tons of apps that I'd miss. I'm open for any kind of solution. Would also transfer my purchases to the new Apple ID, but I found out that's also not possible. Merging two Apple ID's would be also nice though not possible. I'd even hack my own account if I knew and it was possible (if someone knew how, I'd give the right to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) - 2 or more users, shared apps, music, books etc - but not shared email accounts.

Comment: Not exactly as I wanted, but kind of a solution. Great get around, but I'd be a bit happier if I could have 1 account total. Do you think I'll ever be able to merge them? Then I'd do it without hesitation.

Comment: I've had 2 accounts since forever - one of those who had an iTunes account years before iCloud was invented. Don't hold your breath on ever being able to merge them ;)

Comment: Really. That's kinda sad. Isn't there any way to contact Apple about this? I was trying, but I couldn't find a contact email? They could work on it. Actually there are many people who suffer from the same problem according to the forums I visited.

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com/ is the only place to go. I very much doubt it will be the first time it's been requested ;) I just checked back to find how long my 2 accounts have been waiting for a merge function…since 2005

Comment: Sad to hear that. Thanks anyway! I think I'll report it (maybe it gives a push) and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

Go here and log in: https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

Under "Apple ID and Primary Email Address", click Edit. Change your email address here.

Comment: then the brother will change it back again… 2 users, 1 ID, bad idea.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit misleading so I edited my post a bit. The thing I'd like to do is renaming the @icloud address. Currently I use a gmail account as main address for my Apple ID until I solve this.